# Flex nav ul bar not centerd on 768px screens and smaller

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I don't understand why that nav ul bar won't center on smaller screens.

I assume that it has something to do with nav ul's space next to home (and my lack of flex-knowledge).

Here's a pen with which you can shrink the window and see that the left space next to home won't get smaller and makes the horizontal nav bar uncentered.

```css
#header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: baseline;
  border: solid black;
  flex: 1;
  background-image: url(fresh-snow.png);
  background-color: #480459;
  color: white;
}

nav {
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
}

nav ul {
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrapper">
  <hgroup>
    <h1>Marina Heide</h1>
    <h2>Översättare</h2>
    <h3>från svenska, norska, danska till franska</h3>
  </hgroup>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">kontakta mig</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">vem jag är</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div id="main"> .
  <p>Jag översätter böcker, webbsidor, serier och filmer.
    <p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/cykelcykel/pen/eYYBMpq

I'd like the nav bar to be centered when flex-direction is set to column.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<div>` may not be the child of a `<ul>`. Fix that first.

Comment: Sorry, I've mismatched W3's dropdown menu code with my nav ul code. I've deleted it.
I've added a padding of 0 to the ul and it looks like I've fixed the list issue though. Did I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 40px padding on the left for the element **ul class naviation**. In bigger screen, that 40px is almost negligible. So it seems like the navbar is centre aligned. But if you look closely, you will see that the navbar is slightly little to the right side. Add the below code to cancel out the left padding.

```
nav ul {
    border: solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ashfaq_haq/pen/VwwmEdv

Answer (score 0):

In `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) #header-wrapper` you should add line `align-items: center;`

Example https://jsfiddle.net/6oaj2c3q/